# My ubuntu EC2 is timing out in the browser even with the correct security group setings

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have tried everything, this is my last hope before I give up on ever working with AWS again. My security group setting allow port 3000 which is being forwarded to port 80 already. I have rebooted, done a stop start, created a new AWS account, and allowed traffic on port 80. Does anyone know of what else this could be?

My local OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

[image: Security Group settings]

Comment: kinda off topic for here, but make sure you have a public ip assigned to the instance and verify that your AMI doesn't have a local firewall enabled. sudo ufw status, sudo ufw disable (to rely on security group). Also can use something like tcpdump to sniff the traffic and see if it is making it to the image..

Comment: What do you mean when you say "port 3000 which is being forwarded to port 80"? Is the web server running on port 80 or port 3000? If you login to the instance and `curl localhost:80`, does it return a web page? This will check without requiring any network configuration.

Comment: I do have a public ip assigned, and i just ran sudo ufw disable however there was no change :( but i did check and it does seem to be making it there just fine

Comment: My repo is running on port 300 and i used "sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i etho0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000" but actually i just saw that curl localhost:80 is returning connection refused @JohnRotenstein

Comment: You'll need to get it working with `localhost` before attempting to debug connections from outside the instance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you, i really appreciate the help! i think that got me moving in the right direction, weirdly its now able to connect to port 80 in the instance but its still timing out in the browser... any ideas? (its a pretty simply app and im not using MySQL or any other database, just javascript and react)

Answer (score 1):

To make port 80 accessible to a computer on the Internet (assuming that it is working on `localhost`):

- The Amazon EC2 instance should be in a **public subnet** (if you can SSH to it, then this is true)
- A **public IP address** should be assigned to the instance (again, if you can SSH to it, then this is true)
- A **Security Group** associated with the instance should permit inbound access on port 80 from `0.0.0.0/0` (meaning the whole Internet)

There is no need for the Inbound Rule that references port 3000 since you are wanting incoming traffic on port 80 only (I presume).

If your app is still timing-out with the above configuration, then you'll need to debug what it is attempting to do. You could, for example, temporarily open the Security Group for **all ports** just to confirm that it is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you i think this helped narrow down the issue, its now just stating that the connection is refused when i attempted to open my ip in the browser. Just so strange that this started happening randomly. I deployed a similar app a couple weeks ago and it worked without any trouble.

Comment: So for anyone who is also also having this issue, i still have no indication where the issue may originate from, however it tried it again last night and nothing changed but once i tried this morning it worked perfectly... no idea if it might be an issue with my machine or something different.